# Multiple counts on one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, count

I have to solve the following task in SQL Server: I have to count different times on one column from the following two tables.

- Table `Project` contains the bookings from users on different projects.
- Table `User` contains the membership of the users to different teams.
- Table `Result` includes the result of the query I need.

I need the number of users (not the number of bookings) of the different teams booking on the projects in a specific time period.

With `Count distinct` I can count the `All_Users` column. But how to count the rest?

Can somebody give me a hint?

Table **Project**:

```
Project  Date          User
-----------------------------
P1       01.02.2017    John
P1       01.02.2017    Mary
P1       01.02.2017    Molly
P2       01.02.2017    John
P2       02.02.2017    Paul
P2       05.02.2017    Bill
P2       06.02.2017    Emily
P3       03.04.2017    Steve
P3       04.04.2017    Steve
P3       05.04.2017    John
```

Table **User**:

```
User    Team
-------------
John    EXT
Emily   BI
Steve   BC
Bill    NT
Mary    EXT
Molly   BC
Paul    NT
```

Table **Result**:

```
Projekt ALL_USERS   TEAM_BI-BC-NT   TEAM_BI TEAM_BC TEAM_NT TEAM_EXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------
P1         3              1             0       0      0       2
P2         4              3             1       0      2       1
P3         2              1             0       1      0       1
```

Comment: Looks like a pivot problem: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***please*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: edit the question with ur expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.projekt, count(*) as all_users, 
       sum(case when team in ('BI', 'BC', 'NT') then 1 else 0 end) as bi_bc_nt_cnt,
       sum(case when team = 'BI' then 1 else 0 end) as bi_cnt,
       sum(case when team = 'BC' then 1 else 0 end) as bc_cnt,
       sum(case when team = 'NT' then 1 else 0 end) as nt_cnt,
       sum(case when team = 'EXT' then 1 else 0 end) as ext_cnt
from project p join
     user u
     on p.user = u.user
group by p.projekt;
```

Based on your comment, you need some sort of `distinct`.  Let me stick with the same structure and do this in a subquery:

```
select p.projekt, count(*) as all_users, 
       sum(case when u.team in ('BI', 'BC', 'NT') then 1 else 0 end) as bi_bc_nt_cnt,
       sum(case when u.team = 'BI' then 1 else 0 end) as bi_cnt,
       sum(case when u.team = 'BC' then 1 else 0 end) as bc_cnt,
       sum(case when u.team = 'NT' then 1 else 0 end) as nt_cnt,
       sum(case when u.team = 'EXT' then 1 else 0 end) as ext_cnt
from (select distinct projekt, user
      from project p
     ) p join
     user u
     on p.user = u.user
group by p.projekt;
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. But with sum i get the number of bookings. And I Need the number of users who book. A user can book several times on a Project and should only Count once.